# How to request multiple Retrofit2 Call and callback once it all requests finished?

Tags: android, retrofit2

I want to upload all images using retrofit2 and now i am uploading each image as a individual call with success and failure callback, but how can i change as a single request.

Comment: can you post your code what you have done here ?

Comment: Retrofit allows multiple data upload with Multi-part hash-map. The thing you need is make your API supporting the same.

Comment: You will need to dive into the world of Rxjava to do concurrent network requests, combine the responses and return an observable.